# Using Django Model: Concatenating Model Fields

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

This appears easy in my head, but still can't get it done.
This is my model, and it's working as I'd like, though I admit it can be better.

'''
from django.db import models

class Engineers(models.Model):

```
position = (
    ('NOC', 'NOC'),
    ('Supervisor', 'Supervisor'), 
    ('Site Manager','Site Manager'), 
    ('Site Engineer', 'Site Engineer'),
    )
region = (
    ('SS','South-South'),('SW','SW'),('SE','SE'), 
    ('NE','NE'),('NW','NW'),('NC','NC'),
    )


firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
position = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=position)
workarea = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=region)
face = models.ImageField(upload_to='', height_field=15, width_field=9, blank=True)
```

'''
So the issue is, instead of asking the user to enter a username, I want the username field to be automatically populated with the firstname.lastname concatenated like firstname + '.' lastname. in the database. How do I get this done?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: A first name may have spaces though? And names may not be unique? Although this is easy (do it in your view or forms code) there are many edgecases.

Answer (score 1):

As @abdul-aziz-barkat said it is not recommended as this can lead to duplication but if you still want to do it, one way is to implement `save` method in the model, like this

```
  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
      if self.username in (None,''):
           self.usename = "%s.%s"%(self.first_name,self.last_name)
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```